# Cant get props after using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a react app which is made by: app.js with state passing props to another class "ThumbnailAreas"  where Im using the map function to distribute props over single "ThumbnailArea". In this "ThumbnailArea", which is a const, I have two elements: a "ThumbnailTitle" and a "ThumbnailGroup". In the "ThumbnailGroup" I have another map function in other to create the thumbnails passed by props, but I get "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

I believe the issue is due to the first map function, since I have both "ThumbnailTitle" and "ThumbnailArea" inside of it and it will run over the "ThumbnailArea" multiple times, but I cant solve it.

When I console.log "console.log(this.props.texturas)" in my "ThumbnailGroup" I get this:

[image]

this is my state:

```
this.state = {

            activeTab: 'Tab 1',

            thumbnails: [
                {
                    tituloThumbnail: 'Costas',
                    texturas: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
                },
                {
                    tituloThumbnail: 'Pernas',
                    texturas: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
                },
                {
                    tituloThumbnail: 'Pés',
                    texturas: ['A', 'B']
                },
                {
                    tituloThumbnail: 'Porta',
                    texturas: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
                },
            ],

            tabs: [
                {
                    tituloTab: 'Tab 1',
                    colecoes: ['Colecao 1', 'Colecao 2', 'Colecao 3', 'Colecao 4', 'Colecao 5', 'Colecao 6', 'Colecao 7', 'Colecao 8'],
                },
                {
                    tituloTab: 'Tab 2',
                    colecoes: ['Colecao 1'],
                },
                {
                    tituloTab: 'Tab 3',
                    colecoes: ['Colecao 1', 'Colecao 2', 'Colecao 3'],
                },
                {
                    tituloTab: 'Tab 4',
                    colecoes: ['Colecao 1', 'Colecao 2', 'Colecao 3', 'Colecao 4'],
                }
            ]
        };
    }
```

my ThumbnailsAreas.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';

import ThumbnailArea from './ThumbnailArea';

import './ThumbnailAreas.css';

class ThumbnailAreas extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className={["section", "thumbnailAreas"].join(' ')}>

                {this.props.thumbnailAreas.map(thumbnailArea => {
                        return <ThumbnailArea
                            titulo={thumbnailArea.tituloThumbnail}
                            texturas={thumbnailArea.texturas}
                        />
                    }
                )
                }

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ThumbnailAreas;
```

ThumbnailArea.js

```
import ThumbnailTitle from './ThumbnailTitle';
import ThumbnailGroup from './ThumbnailGroup';

const ThumbnailArea = (props) => (

    <div>
        <ThumbnailTitle
            titulo={props.titulo}
        />

        <ThumbnailGroup
            texturas={props.texturas}
        />

    </div>
);
export default ThumbnailArea;
```

thumbnailGroup.js

```
import Thumbnail from './Thumbnail';

class ThumbnailGroup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className={["column", "group"].join(' ')}>

                {
                    this.props.texturas.map(thumbnail => {
                            return <Thumbnail
                                textura={thumbnail}/>
                        }
                    )
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ThumbnailGroup;
```

and it should look something like this (thumbnails are hard coded, should match the number of "texturas"):

[image]

console.log of props from "ThumbnailAreas"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the entire `state` directly into `ThumbnailAreas` then then the way your are accessing your `props` seems incorrect

```
{this.props.thumbnailAreas.map(thumbnailArea => {
        return <ThumbnailArea
            titulo={thumbnailArea.tituloThumbnail}
            texturas={thumbnailArea.texturas}
        />
    }
)}
```

To debug, I recommend either `console.log` the `props` in the `render` method or you can install [react chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) that gives you access into `state` & `props` for every component rendered.

Comment: I'll get the extension, thank you. To pass props to 'ThumbnailAreas' Im using '<ThumbnailAreas thumbnailAreas={this.state.thumbnails}/>'

Comment: @NelsonSilva I have updated my answer. Using the code should work now.

Comment: Im getting 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' on that function. Also, shouldnt "this.state.thumbnails" already send only the thumbnails as props by "thumbnailAreas" ? I can set the "ThumbnailTitle"...

Comment: Updated my answer. Also looks like the problem might be in your `ThumbnailArea` component. Paste its code also.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/2x3mx2y0wr I created taking your code. Looks to be working.